# Find the left coset of this group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Find the left cosets of $H$ in $G$, $G=\mathbb{R}^*$,  $H=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, where $H$ is a subgroup of $G$. How do I go about doing this? I can't list the sets of $G$ and $H$ like I do if the questions says Integers.

Comment: Presumably this question refers to a particular group, probably one mentioned as prelude to a series of questions. Perhaps a screenshot of your text's page would be helpful.

Comment: I think he means $\;G=\Bbb R^*=\;$ the multiplicative group of the reals, and $\;H:=\Bbb R_{>0}\;$ the multiplicative subgroup of the positive reals.

Comment: Ah there we are. Yeah the markup gave me confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that cosets form a partition of the original group $G$ into disjoint subsets, and that a coset is defined by any of its elements, i.e. $y\in xH$ if and only if $yH=xH$. So the most basic and straightforward way for forming cosets is as follows:

- First of all, $H$ itself is a coset.
- If $H=G$, we're done. Otherwise, pick any element $x_1\in G$, $x_1\notin H$. Then $x_1H$ is a new coset.
- If $H\cup x_1H=G$, we're done. Otherwise, we haven't covered all of $G$ yet, so we can find an element $x_2\in G$, $x_2\notin H\cup x_1H$. Then $x_2H$ is a new coset.
- Continue in this fashion until the entire group $G$ has been covered by these cosets.

Apply this procedure to the question at hand. First of all, $H=\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is a coset in $G=\mathbb{R}^{*}$. Now pick any element $x_1\in G$, $x_1\notin H$ (pick something simple). Then $x_1H$ is a new coset. What is $x_1H$? Then you'll see whether the two cosets $H$ and $x_1H$ have already covered all of $G=\mathbb{R}^{*}$. If yes, you're done. If no, then pick another element, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: define

$$\phi:G\to\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\phi(r)=\begin{cases}0,\,&r>0\\{}\\1,\;&r<0\end{cases}$$

Prove that $\;\phi\;$ is a group homomorphism, and now find $\;\ker\phi\;$ ...

Comment: Of course this is it, but I would have defined $\varphi(x)=x/|x|$, giving a totally multiplicative formulation, and obviously a homomorphism, to boot.

Comment: I havent learn homomorphisms yet is there an easier way

Comment: @Lubin YOur idea is very good, yet it should not be a problem to go from a multiplicative group to an additive one. Yet the OP hasn't yet studied homomorphisms...